# How to put a video camera feed in a 3d scene with a 3d sphere component

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I am learning aframe VR framework, studied all the tutorials and [examples](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/) I can find, but I could not find an example to call web camera and put a 3d component like a sphere in the camera video scene like pokemon go does, anybody has a pointer about this or can give me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple A-Frame components providing support for webcams:

- https://github.com/flysonic10/aframe-passthrough
- https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-video-billboard

Both include instructions for getting started.